# How do I to display Large Tiff Images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, tiff, geotiff

I want to display large multi-page/document TIFF files in a web app. The images can have multiple resolutions (i.e. each page can vary in resolution size) and some are very large (50000+ x 20000+ pixels). Their compression algorithms can vary from LZW to CCITT T.6, but most are CCITT T.6.

I know modern web browsers do not support displaying tiff images natively. Instead, I have been trying to use libraries to display these images. The libraries I have tried include the following:

- [image-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-js) and [tiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff) by Zakodium

  - Problems: Memory and possibly unable to handle CCITT T.6 compression
- [tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js)

  - Problems: Memory
- [openseadragon](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon) with [GeoTIFFTileSource](https://github.com/pearcetm/GeoTIFFTileSource)

  - Problems: Unable to integrate GeoTiffTileSource plugin due to lack of experience. I have don't know how to integrate the plugin into my project since the release is just the whole repo and I do not understand how to import the project's release into my CRA project.
- [geotiff.js](https://geotiffjs.github.io/)

  - Problems: Does not display images with CCITT T.6 compression.

Since my image is 50000+ x 20000+ pixels at 200 or 400 DPI and some are RGB, I believe I run into most browser's memory limit (2GB in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox I believe). How do image viewers handle this? Is there processing that needs to be done to handle these images? I don't believe most viewers will display all the pixels since most screens are not that high so I must be missing something fundamentally.